# What's the fastest way to download 100,000 files of 50kB average using Azure NodeJS Functions?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

I'm writing a backup program which should copy all the files uploaded during the day by all the customers and store them on an Azure Blob Storage.
I'm using the Function Chaining pattern to backup one customer after another.   I did that to keep the logs of each customer grouped but I guess I could use the fan-out fan-in pattern too.

Here's the structure of my code:

- A trigger function gets the list of all the customers and send it to the orchestrator function
- For each account, the orchestrator calls a sub-orchestrator function which

  - gets the list of file ids to backup
  - Group these files by batches of 250 and call the DownloadFiles function to download and upload them to the blob storage. (I group the files to avoid hitting the 5min limit but for one batch, I can still re-use the same HTTP agent)

Here's my DownloadFiles function:

```js
const request = require('request');
const { getContainerURL, uploadStreamToBlob } = require('../blob-storage');
const log = require('../log');

function downloadFile(options, containerURL, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request
      .get(options)
      .on('error', err => reject(err))
      .on('response', async (res) => {
        if (res.statusCode === 404) reject('HTTP 404');
        else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
          reject(new Error(`got response code ${res.statusCode} for file ID ${id}\n${res.statusMessage}`));
        } else {
          try {
            await uploadStreamToBlob(containerURL, `photos/${id}`, res);
          } catch (err) {
            reject(new Error(`Cannot upload fileID to blob: ${id}`));
          }
          resolve();
        }
      });
  });
}

async function downloadFileWithRetry(options, containerURL, id, retry = false) {
  try {
    await downloadFile(options, containerURL, id);
    return null;
  } catch (error) {
    if (retry) return downloadFileWithRetry(options, containerURL, id, false);
    return error;
  }
}

module.exports = async function (context) {
  const { containerName, token, slice } = context.bindings.name;
  const containerURL = getContainerURL(containerName);
  const finalResult = {
    nbErrors: 0,
    nbFiles: 0,
  };

  const sliceSize = 8;
  for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i += sliceSize) {
    const promises = slice.slice(i, i + sliceSize).map(async (file) => {
      const options = {
        url: `https://${process.env.HOSTNAME}/download/`,
        forever: true, // use the forever agent
        qs: { id: file.id, auth: token },
      };
      return {
        file,
        err: await downloadFileWithRetry(options, containerURL, file.id, true),
      };
    });
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    for (let j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
      const res = results[j];
      if (!res.err) {
        finalResult.nbFiles++;
      } else {
        log(`Could not download file ID ${res.file.id}`);
        log(res.err);
        finalResult.nbErrors++;
      }
    }
  }

  return finalResult;
};
```

On average, the DownloadFiles function lasts 15.7s for 250 files. I could probably improve the throughput by increasing the number of files to 500 or 1,000 but since some instances took 250s, I'm afraid to hit the 5min max duration of a function.
Is there a better approach to this problem?

**EDIT** I've also used the https.globalAgent with keepAlive set to true and it's much faster than using the forever agent of request.

Comment: I would suggest you create two functions inside your function app. One function that puts name of your customer into a queue. And another function that is triggered by that queue. Then each load is not limited by 5 mins and which is more can be parallelized. If you like the approach ping me, I will creat a demo for you.

Comment: This means the function that downloads the files will have to re-create the HTTP Agent / Client for every file. Before porting the code to Azure Functions, it was running on a VM. I observed that setting the `forever` option to true in `request` significantly improved the performances. Therefore I'm pretty sure your approach would not be beneficial.  
I think I will give the full file list to a function, save the current file id in a blob after a successful download, let it timeout after 5min and restart it wherever it stopped

Comment: Yes, Gpack, you have a perfectly valid concern. However I would recommend you give it a try and put your http client outside the function scope to share the client within one function host. You can see the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#http-agent-examples-javascript). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908101/3407539) answer will inspire you for further improvement.

Comment: Btw, the timeout can be increase in your case to 10 mins. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout), as noted by Jay Gong below.

Comment: I will increase the timeout but it seems like the last thing to do after fine-tuning everything else.
Your previous comment is very interesting. So I need to set `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 600;` to avoid reaching the connection limit and make sure that the DownloadFile function uses http.globalAgent.
But what if I insert 1,000 files in my queue faster than they can be downloaded? Is it correct to say that I will have 600 instances of my DownloadFile function running in // and the 601st will wait until one of them has finished?

Comment: Great questions. _But what if I insert 1,000...?_ Two things to note here. 1) You [can control](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2)#sample-hostjson) number of concurrent executions for your queue. 2) You can have more than one file name per message. _Is it correct to say that I will have 600 instances ...?_ You should differentiate between function host and function execution. If you share the http client you should have less than 100 with your load. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox)

Comment: If my suggestions helped, would you accept my answer out of them?

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create two functions inside your function app. One function that puts name of your customer into a queue. And another function that is triggered by that queue. Then each load is not limited by 5 mins and which is more can be parallelized. If you like the approach ping me, I will create a demo for you.

I would recommend you give it a try and put your http client outside the function scope to share the client within one function host. You can see the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#http-agent-examples-javascript). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906463/azure-functions-javascript-node-js-http-call-good-practices/47908101#47908101) answer will inspire you for further improvement.

*But what if I insert 1,000 files in my queue faster than they can be downloaded?*
Two things to note for your questions. 
1) You [can control](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2)#sample-hostjson) number of concurrent executions for your queue. 
2) You can have more than one file name per message.

*Is it correct to say that I will have 600 instances of my DownloadFile function running in // and the 601st will wait until one of them has finished?*
You should differentiate between function host and function execution. If you share the http client you should have less than 100 with your load. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

Answer (score 1):

Azure function does have a 5 minute timeout limit, firstly it's the default value with Consumption plan, as for App Service plan v2 default value is 30 minutes.

For your situation the direc method is set the `functionTimeout` property in `host.json`.

Here is the [timeout duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout):

[image]

The below is the host.json sample:

```
{
"functionTimeout": "00:05:00"
}
```

Further more information about functionTimeout you could refer to this doc: [functionTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout).

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm not downloading the 100,000 files at once but instead, I'm splitting them in groups of 250.
So you're simply suggesting to raise the timeout limit and the number of files in the groups to 500?